# Java MySQL prevent race condition

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, prepared-statement, race-condition

I write a java application that starts asynchronous threads to read and update values from the same database. Each thread gets the connection from a connection pool (c3p0). I have to prevent race conditions because I have to update entries based on their current values. So reading data with a `SELECT` statement and then update it with an `UPDATE` statement would cause a race condition and so it would not be thread safe. I already found some solutions how to prevent such race conditions but I still have some questions.

For example I can use kind of that `UPDATE ExampleTable SET ExampleValue = ExampleValue + '5' WHERE Id = '10'` to increment values thread safe. I read that this is an atomic statement. So my first question is: Is executing a `PreparedStatement` in java always thread safe? I think so because (if autoCommit is true) every single executed statement is a transaction and transactions are atomic, right? If yes, is that also the case if I call a procedure with a statement or if I put multiple queries in one statement separated through semicolons?

I also read that I can set autoCommit to false and execute multiple statements befor commiting, wich also achieves thread safety because no other statement can interrupt a transaction. Is that right?

Are there any further solutions to prevent such race conditions?

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2713427/898478) answers some of your questions, did you check it? Specially: *"Give every thread its own connection"*. I do it this way through a connection pool and I don't have any race conditions (although I use PostgreSQL not MySQL).

Comment: I use a Connection Pool and every thread has its own Connection object from the pool. But race conditions are still possible when using separate statements for reading and writing.

Comment: As EJP answers, use `SELECT FOR UPDATE`, this way you only have one statement. If you want to execute more queries/updates or `SELECT FOR UPDATE` is not an option, you need to wrap them into a transaction (of course still one connection per thread).

Comment: @m0skit0 Wouldn't I need a second statement to execute the update? For example: `SELECT counter_field FROM child_codes FOR UPDATE;` `UPDATE child_codes SET counter_field = counter_field + 1;`.

Comment: As for your before last question: the i in [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) should answer that. Quote from the link: "... concurrent execution of transactions results in a system state that would be obtained if transactions were executed serially ...". Just make sure you use the right [isolation level](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28database_systems%29#Isolation_levels).

Comment: So when I use for example SERIALIZABLE isolation level and do all the work in one transaction there wont be a race condition. If I choose a lower isolation level I have to use things like the `SELECT FOR UPDATE` statement to achieve a lock. Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is executing a PreparedStatement in java always thread safe?

I'm not sure what this means. You would only use a `PreparedStatement` and indeed its underlying `Connection` from a single thread, so the issue doesn't arise.

> I think so because (if autoCommit is true) every single executed statement is a transaction and transactions are atomic, right? If yes, is that also the case if I call a procedure with a statement or if I put multiple queries in one statement separated through semicolons?

I thought so. What you're really asking is whether `PreparedStatement` is *atomic,* whether across threads or processes, and the answer to that is 'no' unless you use auto-commit. If you're using transactions, it is the transaction which is atomic. [In fact it is always the transaction which is atomic, but in auto-commit mode it is co-extensive with the statement.]

> I also read that I can set autoCommit to false and execute multiple statements befor commiting, wich also achieves thread safety because no other statement can interrupt a transaction. Is that right?

It achieves *atomicity*. Thread safety is another thing entirely.

What you may be looking for is `SELECT... FOR UPDATE` within a non-auto-committed transaction. It locks the returned rows so that they can't be returned by another such statement until this transaction is committed. Or else constructions like `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY [IGNORE|UPDATE]`.

Comment: What about multiple statements?

Comment: Do you mean that I should not use auto-commit at all? Isn't autoCommit the default setting? Can you please answer the other questions? Is executing one statement always thread safe?

Comment: @stonar96  The answer I linked already answers the "one statement" question.

Comment: @EJP Sorry but your answer confuses me even more. I thought when I disable auto-commit and I commit manually after executing my statements there will be no race conditions at all because it is one transaction (atomic). Why do I need the  `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` then?

Comment: @EJP Thank you. One question: Doesn't atomic mean that the transaction can't be interrupted by another transaction -> Race condition is not possible? So why wouldn't it work when I use a normal `SELECT` statement and then the `UPDATE` statement in a single transaction?

Comment: @stonar96 You need to have a good look [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking-reads.html).